# WCF REST service returns 405: method not allowed for jQuery AJAX GET

Tags: json, jquery, wcf-rest, http-status-code-405

Even after going through this post
[wcf REST Services and JQuery Ajax Post: Method not allowed (3)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6633648/wcf-rest-services-and-jquery-ajax-post-method-not-allowed)

I cannot get past 405: Method not allowed when attempting to invoke a method on my WCF REST service via the following AJAX call:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: 'http://mydomain.com/service1/service.svc/json/getsupportedagencies',
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    failure: function (msg) {
        alert(msg);
    },
    success: function (agencies) {
        alert("success via REST");
        $.each(agencies, function (i, a) {
            viewModel.agencies.push(new agency(a.Name, a.FullName));
        });
    }
});
```

The service interface is defined as follows:

```
 [ServiceContract]
public interface IService1
{
    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "GET",
        RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
       ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, UriTemplate = "getsupportedagencies")]
    AgencyDTO[] GetSupportedAgencies();

  // other methods
}
```

After running into threads on cross-domain issues, I manually added a Global.asax file to the webservice project, also adding the following method method:

```
 protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin",
                         "http://localhost:80");

        if (HttpContext.Current.Request.HttpMethod == "OPTIONS")
        {
            HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods",
                          "GET, POST");
            HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers",
                          "Content-Type, Accept");
            HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age",
                          "1728000");
            HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
        }

    }
```

My service model configuration in web.config looks like this:

```
<system.serviceModel>       
        <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" />     
        <services>
            <service behaviorConfiguration="ServiceBehavior" name="Services.Service1">
                <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
                <endpoint address="basic" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="Services.Contracts.IService1" />
                <endpoint address="json" 
                    behaviorConfiguration="JsonBehavior"
                    binding="webHttpBinding" 
                    contract="Services.Contracts.IService1" />
            </service>   
        </services>
        <behaviors>
        <endpointBehaviors>
            <behavior name="JsonBehavior">
                <webHttp />
            </behavior>
        </endpointBehaviors>
    <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="ServiceBehavior">
     <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
     <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
    </behavior>
   </serviceBehaviors>
  </behaviors>      
    </system.serviceModel>
```

My unit test to the service using the following code passes:

```
[Test]
 public void TestGetAgencyForLocation()
       {
           var client = new WebClient();

           var response = client.DownloadString(
                  "http://mydomain.com/service1/service.svc/json/getsupportedagencies");
           Assert.IsTrue(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(response));

           var agencies= JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(response);
           Assert.IsNotNull(agencies);
       }
```

If I post the url "http://mydomain.com/service1/service.svc/json/getsupportedagencies" in Chrome or IE, I get the correct server response in JSON format.

Yes, with all of this in place, I still get 405: method not allowed.

TIA.

Comment: Thanks you solved my problem with these line "HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods",
                          "GET, POST");"

Answer (score 0):

Me resolved this issue by adding below code in WCF project **Global.asax** file

```
protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
            if (HttpContext.Current.Request.HttpMethod == "OPTIONS")
            {
                HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, PUT, DELETE");

                HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type, Accept");
                HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "1728000");
                HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
            }
        }
```